# PHP - How to delete column with no header into txt file

Tags: php, file, row

I have txt file where the first row contains the column names. But some rows have no title, I would like to know if there is any solution to remove those rows without column names into my txt file?

To access to my txt file:

```
$handleFile= fopen("/opt/lampp/htdocs/ngs/tmp/testfile.txt","r");
$dataTestFile=fgetcsv($handleFile,0,"\t");
```

Here's an example:

```
Data1;Data2;;Input;;
aaaaa;ferfs;;alpha;dfdfd;
```

**Desired output:**

```
Data1;Data2;Input;
aaaaa;ferfs;alpha;
```

First row is column names, and some of them haven't any names, I need to remove all columns which have no names.

Thanks.

Comment: it's better to put some sample of the txt file

Comment: @FareedMN. True, I added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this :

```
<?php
$data=file_get_contents("/opt/lampp/htdocs/ngs/tmp/testfile.txt");
$array=explode("\n",$data); // putting rows in an array
$first_line=$array['0'];
$first_line_array=explode("|",$first_line);
$removed_columns=array();
foreach ($first_line_array as $key=>$value){
if(strstr("   ",$value) !== FALSE){
    array_push($removed_columns,$key);
}
}
// now we know what columns to remove
$new_line='';
$new_array=array();
$new_line_array=array();
$old_line_array=array();
for($x=0;$x<count($array);$x++){
$old_line_array=explode("|",$array[$x]);
for($y=0;$y<count($old_line_array);$y++){
    if(!in_array($y,$removed_columns)){
        array_push($new_line_array,$old_line_array[$y]);
    }
    }
    $new_line=join('|',$new_line_array);

    array_push($new_array,$new_line);

    $new_line='';
    $new_line_array=array();
    $old_line_array=array();

    } 
    $new_data=join("\n",$new_array);
    file_put_contents("/opt/lampp/htdocs/ngs/tmp/testfilenew.txt",$new_data)
    ?>
```

In the end you get the file (testfilenew.txt) which has the data you want

Comment: thx so much for your help but unfortunatly, I cannot test your script, I have an error `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function split()`. I am using PHP 7.

Comment: well i'm using 5.2 :) sorry

Comment: @FareeMN. Thaks for your solution. With explode I don't have any uncaught error. I actually used the pipe (|) in my data model but it was just to illustrate column separations. each column is separated with a tabulation. Should I removed all lines in your script with | ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to 1st read the 1st row and store the column nos with empty data in an array.

Once you have the array you can use the below code to skip the columns:

```
$columns = array(1,3); // columns to skip

while (($data = fgetcsv($dataTestFile, 1000, "|")) !== FALSE) {
        echo("<tr>\r\n");
        foreach ($data as $index=>$val) {
                if (!in_array($index+1, $columns)) {
                        echo("\t<td>$val</td>\r\n");
                }
        }
        echo("</tr>\r\n");
} //end while
```